# Using ip_hash on a SINGLE upstream server only in nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We are using nginx for load balancing.  We just pushed a new server online with a massive upgrade to our platform for testing before we roll it out.  We want to make sure it's working for, so we have weights set to send roughly 10% of the traffic to that server.

The problem is that we need to ensure that if the user is servers that server, they will always get that server for future sessions.  This is easily done with `ip_hash`, but what we really want is for the other services to use a round-robin strategy while ONLY that one server uses ip_hash.

Is something like that possible at all?  Here is our upstream.conf

```
upstream apps  {
   ip_hash;
   server 10.134.13.38:80 weight=3; # app-00
   server 10.134.13.46:80 weight=3; # app-01
   server 10.134.24.30:80 weight=3; # app-02
   server 10.134.8.153:80 weight=1; # app-new-test
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`split_clients`](http://nginx.org/r/split_clients) directive and define two upstreams.

```
upstream apps {
   server 10.134.13.38:80; # app-00
   server 10.134.13.46:80; # app-01
   server 10.134.24.30:80; # app-02
}

upstream apps_new_test {
   server 10.134.8.153:80; # app-new-test
}

split_clients "${remote_addr}AAA" $upstream_app {
    10% apps_new_test;
    *   apps;
}

server {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://$upstream_app;
}
```

Comment: This is great.  After nginx serves either apps or apps_new_test, is it sticky so that that user will always get that same upstream?

Answer (score 0):

There is a single request distribution policy in use for a single `upstream` block. So, you cannot achieve your goal like this.

You could try something like assigning a cookie for users coming to the `app-new-test` server. The cookie assignment would be done by the new app running on the server.

Then you would test for that cookie value in `server` block with `if` directive, and then use `proxy_pass http://10.134.8.153;`. For example:

```
server {
    if ($cookie_upstream = "app-test-new") {
        proxy_pass http://10.134.8.153;
    }
    proxy_pass http://apps;
}
```